# Can I find the angle?

Tags: geometry

Look at the diagram
[image: geometry question]

I know $\theta$, $D$ and ratio of $\frac{a}{b}$ (say $k$). I am trying to find out $\alpha$. Is this possible? I couldn't crack it. (I only know the ratio of $a$ to $b$, and I don't know $c$ as well)

**UPDATE**
I think I have found a solution. Look at this.
[image]

x=tan($\theta$)*h

cos($\alpha$)=(2D-x)/a

cos($\alpha$)=2D/(a+b)

ratio of these two => (a+b)/a=2D/(2D-x)

We know a/b and D. We can find x. Since we know $\theta$, we can find $\alpha$.

I am starting a bounty for somebody who can prove this solution wrong. If it is correct, it is mine to keep.

**Update2**

Ok.. My bad.. I am overall decent guy but fall on my face on this one.

Comment: Would you be happy with a solution involving $c$? I think there is no solution not involving $c$.

Comment: C is not known..The solution must be without c.

Comment: You can change $c$ and $\alpha$ together while not changing any of the other known values. There is no solution without $c$ unless there is more information that what is given.

Comment: if we know  D and   theta  then e can calculate all angles of big triangle with base on rectangular  also all it''s sides

Comment: i think we dont  need ratio a/b=k  so start suppose theta is 30 degree   it means that we know angle at the base of  rectangular    which is equal  90-30 =60(angle is arbitrary take any)then we know also angle  at the top  of rectangular side  which is also  90-30=60 we can find adjacent angle by  180-(90-theta) and then make equation of two  first sum of angle is 180 and second exterior angle is sum of it's non adjacent angles so you can find   alpha

Comment: I am not so sure that proof is correct.

Comment: @Frank: I'm unable to parse that comment, but it can't work like that, a) because of what I wrote in my answer and b) because only $\theta$ is being used and you can obviously change $\alpha$ without changing $\theta$.

Comment: @joriki I agree, this is a problem with no solution. I will post another one, which is strangely is possible to solve and it is rather easy. stay tuned

Comment: @joriki, could there be a solution? I think I have found one. Let me hit it up.

Comment: Your alleged solution is unclear to me. Could you write out in equations what you sketched in words at the end? Especially the part "Since we know $\theta$, we can find $\alpha$". None of the equations you've written contains only $\alpha$ and no other unknowns. Note that the two new parameters $x$ and $h$ you introduced are left invariant by the procedure I described in my answer, so they can't determine $\alpha$, since the procedure changes $\alpha$.

Comment: Perhaps a good way for you to see that there can't be a solution is to imagine the line consisting of $a$ and $b$ as a rod that always moves along such that it passes through the corner on the left and the intersection of the vertical line labeled by $h$ with the second oblique line (the one at angle $\theta$). Then if you move the second oblique line and the bottom line upwards together (thus reducing $c$), all that changes is $\alpha$, $a$, $b$ and $c$, whereas $D$, $h$, $x$, $\theta$ and $a/b$ stay the same.

Comment: Frank: there probably is some (perhaps a real-world?) motivation behind this question and the other one you asked. It is unfortunate that you received a negative answer twice. I suggest that you ask a question describing the actual problem, maybe somebody can help you then and that would be much more satisfactory for everyone involved. Just my two cents.

Comment: @theo you are right, there is a real world application. I will tell you guys when we ship.

Comment: @Frank: I'm not surprised :) Best wishes,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Imagine changing $\alpha$ a bit. Now compensate for the change in $a/b$ by moving the top vertex up or down a bit. Now compensate for the change in $D$ by changing $c$ a bit. Now all you've changed is $\alpha$ and $c$, so you can't find $\alpha$ without $c$.

[*Edit:*]

Perhaps an easier way to see that there can't be a solution is to imagine the line consisting of $a$ and $b$ as a rod that always moves along such that it passes through the corner on the left and the intersection of the vertical line labeled by $h$ with the second oblique line (the one at angle $\theta$). Then if you move the second oblique line and the bottom line upwards together (thus reducing $c$), all that changes is $\alpha$, $a$, $b$ and $c$, whereas $D$, $h$, $x$, $\theta$ and $a/b$ stay the same.

Comment: Changing $c$ will change $\alpha$ again, so this doesn't prove anything

Comment: @Hannesh: Perhaps that wasn't sufficiently clear. I meant changing $c$ by simply moving the bottom line up without changing any of the lines further up. I'll include my other explanation from the comments in the answer; perhaps that's more intuitive.

Comment: I will award the bounty to you Joriki as soon as I can.. thanks very much for your support

Comment: Deleted my comment as I noticed that Jiri had brought up the exact same point in his figure.

Answer (score 2):

You can compute $x$ and $h$. (BTW, your second equation should be $\cos(\alpha) = (D+x)/a$.). Even then, you cannot determine $\alpha$.

[image]

You just got the point $S$. According to the [Intercept theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem) all the red lines in the figure passing through $S$ have the same ratio $k = a/b$ but they have different angles $\alpha$ to the horizontal line.

EDIT. I am adding the explicit formulae for $x$ and $h$. We have
$$ (1) \;\;\; \cos(\alpha) = (D+x) / a$$
$$ (2) \;\;\; \cos(\alpha) = 2D / (a+b)$$

From (1) and (2) we get

$$x = D (k-1) / (k+1) $$

Further, we obtain $h$ as
$$ h = x / tan(\theta) $$

Now, the above geometric argument is applied. In addition, we see that $\alpha$ cannot be obtained from the equations (1) and (2) without knowing either $a$ or $a+b$.

Comment: I am having a hard time scrolling back and forth, but this looks like a different diagram than the one above.

Comment: @Greg: I had some problems with the upload of the figure. Should be OK now.

Answer (score 2):

I have copied your image below and added some constructions to help find $\tan(\alpha)$.

[image: value-added copied image]

Note that there are three similar right triangles, each with an angle of $\theta$.  They are similar because they are right triangles and share the opposite (also called vertical) angles near the right arrow under $c\tan(\theta)$.

We can compute the length of the hypotenuse of the right triangle with the dashed, red side and angle of $\theta$ to be $D+c\tan(\theta)$, then compute the dashed, red side to be $D\cos(\theta)+c\sin(\theta)$. From there, it is pretty easy to compute $a$, $a+b$, and then take their ratio.  Solving, we get
$$
\tan(\alpha)=\cot(\theta)-\frac{a/b+1}{a/b}\frac{\cot(\theta)+c/D}{2}
$$
This requires only that we know $a/b$, $c/D$, and $\cot(\theta)$, but $\tan(\alpha)$ is definitely dependent on $c/D$.