# Can I find the distance?

Tags: geometry

Please look at the diagram:

[image: img]

I know $D$, $\alpha$ and $\theta$. I also know the $a/b$ ratio of $k$. I don't know $c$. Can I find out $a$ or $b$ or $a+b$?

Comment: It would have been good style to mention this directly related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59636/can-i-find-the-angle/59642 to avoid unnecessary duplication of efforts.

Comment: sorry this is a different question.. they may look similar but nothing is far from truth..

Comment: I can see it's a different question; otherwise I would have voted to close it as a duplicate. Nevertheless it's clear that some insight might be gained from answers to the other question, and there's no reason not to include a link.

Comment: What is $\alpha$? An angle?

Comment: α is the angle.. Sorry it wasn't clear.

Comment: @joriki, now I see what you mean.. Ok.. good point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a slightly different question to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/59636/12741). But the answer is the same: it is not possible to determine $a$ or $b$ or $a+b$. Look at this figure:

[image]

We can move the red lines anywhere in the $\theta$ cone without changing $\alpha$ and $k=a/b$. But $a$ and $b$ are changed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. It is clear this is not possible.